# HTTPConnection .getresponse() throws an uncatchable error in my GAE app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, httplib

I've got the following piece of code in a GAE app - there's very little to the app but this

```
class Check(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        sites = [    
            [1, 0, 'the google', 'www.google.com',  '555-0123']
        ]

        for site in sites:
            try:
                print "checking " + site[3] + "\r\n"
                conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(site[3])
                conn.request("GET", "/")
                r1 = conn.getresponse()
                print r1.status + "\r\n"
            except: # catch *all* exceptions
                e = sys.exc_info()[0]
                print e
```

This gives me the response:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>
> Please try again in 30 seconds.

If I comment out the line `print r1.status + "\r\n"` the method executes just fine. Shouldn't `except:` catch this exception for me?

More importantly, why is it throwing an exception in the first place?

Comment: BTW, don't you mean `conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(site)` (or `conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(sites[3])`) instead of `conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(site[3])`?

Comment: no, site[3] is the 3rd item in site. it's a 2d array. `for site in sites:`

Comment: `for site in sites` makes `site` a s string, thus `site[3]` is the 4th char in that `site` string.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I'm blind :) Never mind.

Comment: In order to better understand your problem, where does it give you that response? In the console, webpage? How are you running this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is **not** an exception (as in communication transmission code exception), it's just a server response, perfectly valid from the communication transmission prospective.

You need to address that differently, at the communication protocol level, above the communication transmission level.

**Update:** The above note stands for the response you mentioned, which misled me.

How exactly you're getting it I'm not sure, but the reason for the exception is your print line:

```
  File "blah.py", line 187, in post
    print r1.status + "\r\n"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'long' and 'str'
```

You could replace the line with something like this to avoid the exception:

```
print "%s\r\n" % r1.status
```

Comment: it acts like an exception. with the line of code included, I get this every single time. If I mess up a line (forget a colon after an if statement for example), I get the same error

Comment: which is why IMHO it's better to use `logging.exception()` instead of a custom `print e` - at least you get a traceback which usually helps figuring out what's going on.

Comment: I eventually tried _exactly_ your code and got this in the python console for the `print r1.status + "\r\n"` line: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` (slightly different in GAE project: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'long' and 'str'`)